# Is there a way to stop a SoundEffect audio playback?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am using the following code snippet to play .wav files:

```
Stream s = TitleContainer.OpenStream("sounds/MySound.wav");
SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(s);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
effect.Play();
```

Is there a way to stop the sound after it starts playing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `SoundEffectInstance` from your `SoundEffect` then you'll have access to more actions to control your sound.

```cs
Stream s = TitleContainer.OpenStream("sounds/MySound.wav");
SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(s);
var effectInstance = effect.CreateInstance();
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
effectInstance.Play();

// This will stop the sound
effectInstance.Stop();
```